# fetch post method with razor page doesn't send body

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core, fetch, razor-pages

I would like to trasnfer some data from the page to the page model with ajax (fetch api) post.
I manage to get to "OnPostTest" handler, but I don't recive any data - variable "json" is null.
Where is my problem?
Is it on my ajax call or in the razor page model method?
thanks

razor page- page model

```
public JsonResult OnPostTest(string json)
{
    return new JsonResult(json);
}
```

js

```
async function getData() {
    fetch('./test/Test',
        {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({
                json: 'yourValue'
            }),
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.getElementsByName("__RequestVerificationToken")[0].value,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Accept: 'application/json',
            }
        })
        .then(function (res) { return res.json(); })
        .then(function (data) { alert((data)) })
}
```

razor page

```
<form method="post">
    <button type="button" onclick="getData(this)" value="1">send</button>
</form>
```

----Edit----
js

```
async function getData() {
    fetch('./test/Test',
        {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(
                {
                    name: "myname",
                    value: 1,
                    date:new Date()
                }
            ),
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.getElementsByName("__RequestVerificationToken")[0].value,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
            }
        })
        .then(function (res) { return res.json(); })
        .then(function (data) { alert((data)) })
}
```

razor page - page-model

```
public JsonResult OnPostTest([FromBody] ViewModel json)
        {
            return new JsonResult(json.Name);
        }

        public class ViewModel
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Value { get; set; }
            public DateTime date { get; set; }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `headers` need to be changed. Because the bakend receive a string, so the  body should be only a string.

```
fetch('[url]',
        {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(
                 'yourValue'
            ),

            headers: {
                RequestVerificationToken: document.getElementsByName("__RequestVerificationToken")[0].value,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Accept: 'application/json',
            }
        })
        .then(function (res) { return res.json(); })
        .then(function (data) { console.log(data) })
```

Add `[FromBody]` in page handler.

```
  public JsonResult OnPostTest([FromBody]string json)
    {
        return new JsonResult(json);
    }
```

Edit:

If passing the complex object `{name:"myname",value:"5"}`, you need to serilize the object with `JSON.stringify()`.

```
      body: JSON.stringify(
             name:"myname",
             value:"5"
        ),
```

And the bakend should use a complex object to receive.

```
    public JsonResult OnPostTest([FromBody]ViewModel json)
    {
        return new JsonResult(json);
    }
     
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the fast reply ! , i change the 'body' to be only a string and added the [FromBody] to the argument recieved - [FromBody]String json. yet when i check inside the method json = null. and then thats the alert i see on the page . what maybe the problem? also what data type should i use on the method in the razor page if i want to recieve ajson object -- {name:"myname",value:"5"} etc.

Comment: @NirKusan, about this situation, it should be considered separately, refer to this edited answer.